# Strange output (possibly related to tcolorbox)

Tags: hyperref, tcolorbox, fancyhdr, cleveref

I use the `tcolorbox` package to highlight certain theorem environments. I occasionally get very strange behaviour when placing hyperlinks (MWE below). The problem does only seem to occur on macOS. If I compile the same file on Linux (for instance Ubuntu with TeXLive 2017), everything looks normal.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks=true,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,backref=page]{hyperref}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[chapter]

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems,skins,breakable}
\tcolorboxenvironment{defn}{enhanced jigsaw,colframe=blue,sharp corners,interior hidden,breakable,before skip=10pt,after skip=20pt,left=2mm, right=2mm }

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}

\begin{defn}
Some text ...
\end{defn}

\href{url}{Text}

\begin{defn}
\lipsum
\end{defn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Edit: Per the request below, I add the output -- roughly as much as is allowed -- of the log file (when compiling with pdflatex)

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.7.7)  23 AUG 2021 12:00
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**temp.tex
(./temp.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsbook.cls
Document Class: amsbook 2020/05/29 v2.20.6
\linespacing=\dimen138
\normalparindent=\dimen139
\normaltopskip=\skip47
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2020/09/23 v2.17i AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip48

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks15
\ex@=\dimen140
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen141
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count179
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count180
\leftroot@=\count181
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
\classnum@=\count182
\DOTSCASE@=\count183
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box47
\strutbox@=\box48
\big@size=\dimen142
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count184
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count185
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count186
\dspbrk@lvl=\count187
\tag@help=\toks16
\row@=\count188
\column@=\count189
\maxfields@=\count190
\andhelp@=\toks17
\eqnshift@=\dimen143
\alignsep@=\dimen144
\tagshift@=\dimen145
\tagwidth@=\dimen146
\totwidth@=\dimen147
\lineht@=\dimen148
\@envbody=\toks18
\multlinegap=\skip49
\multlinetaggap=\skip50
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks19
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2923.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2924.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msa on input line 376
.

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)
\copyins=\insert199
\abstractbox=\box49
\listisep=\skip51
\c@part=\count191
\c@chapter=\count192
\c@section=\count193
\c@subsection=\count194
\c@subsubsection=\count195
\c@paragraph=\count196
\c@subparagraph=\count197
\c@figure=\count198
\c@table=\count266
\abovecaptionskip=\skip52
\belowcaptionskip=\skip53
\captionindent=\dimen149
\thm@style=\toks20
\thm@bodyfont=\toks21
\thm@headfont=\toks22
\thm@notefont=\toks23
\thm@headpunct=\toks24
\thm@preskip=\skip54
\thm@postskip=\skip55
\thm@headsep=\skip56
\dth@everypar=\toks25
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2021-02-18 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2021-03-18 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count267
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box50
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse-2020-10-
01.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse-generic.
tex)))
Package: lipsum 2021-03-03 v2.3 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
 (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.ltd.tex
File: lipsum.ltd.tex 2021-03-03 v2.3 The Lorem ipsum dummy text
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2021-02-27 v7.00k Hypertext links for LaTeX

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks26
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty
Package: letltxmacro 2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2020-10-07 v3.14 Key value format for package options (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen150
\Hy@linkcounter=\count268
\Hy@pagecounter=\count269

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2021-02-27 v7.00k Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref-langpatches.def
File: hyperref-langpatches.def 2021-02-27 v7.00k Hyperref: patches for babel la
nguages
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count270

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def
File: puenc.def 2021-02-27 v7.00k Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PU ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PU
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `ocgcolorlinks' set `true' on input line 4073.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4192.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4197.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4200.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4207.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing ON on input line 4210.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4445.

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/backref.sty
Package: backref 2021/02/04 v1.41 Bibliographical back referencing

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2019/12/05 v1.9 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty
Package: atveryend-ltx 2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atvery packag
e
with kernel methods
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty
Package: uniquecounter 2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
))
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
86.
))
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count271

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip17
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 4804.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen151

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
)
\Fld@menulength=\count272
\Field@Width=\dimen152
\Fld@charsize=\dimen153
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6075.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6080.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6083.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing ON on input line 6088.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6095.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG ON on input line 6098.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6105.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6145.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6149.

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty
Package: atbegshi-ltx 2020/08/17 v1.0a Emulation of the original atbegshi packa
ge
with kernel methods
)
\Hy@abspage=\count273
\c@Item=\count274
\c@Hfootnote=\count275
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
File: hpdftex.def 2021-02-27 v7.00k Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
\Fld@listcount=\count276
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count277
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip57
)
\c@defn=\count278

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.sty
Package: tcolorbox 2020/10/09 version 4.42 text color boxes

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks27
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen154
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen155

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-li
sts.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box51
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)
Package: pgfrcs 2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
))
Package: pgf 2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2020/09/09 v1.2b Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2020/08/30 v1.4c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 105.

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen156
\Gin@req@width=\dimen157
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks28
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks29

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks30
))
\pgf@x=\dimen158
\pgf@y=\dimen159
\pgf@xa=\dimen160
\pgf@ya=\dimen161
\pgf@xb=\dimen162
\pgf@yb=\dimen163
\pgf@xc=\dimen164
\pgf@yc=\dimen165
\pgf@xd=\dimen166
\pgf@yd=\dimen167
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read2
\c@pgf@counta=\count279
\c@pgf@countb=\count280
\c@pgf@countc=\count281
\c@pgf@countd=\count282
\t@pgf@toka=\toks31
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks32
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks33
\pgf@sys@id@count=\count283

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.d
ef
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-p
df.def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.
code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count284
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count285
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.
code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen168
\pgfmath@count=\count286
\pgfmath@box=\box52
\pgfmath@toks=\toks34
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks35
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks36
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count287
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen169
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen170
\pgf@picminy=\dimen171
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen172
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen173
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen174
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen175
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen176
\pgf@xx=\dimen177
\pgf@xy=\dimen178
\pgf@yx=\dimen179
\pgf@yy=\dimen180
\pgf@zx=\dimen181
\pgf@zy=\dimen182
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconst
ruct.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen183
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen184
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage
.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen185
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen186
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
\pgfpic=\box53
\pgf@hbox=\box54
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box55
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count288
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicst
ate.code.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen187
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransform
ations.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen188
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen189
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen190
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.cod
e.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.c
ode.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathproce
ssing.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen191
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.cod
e.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
\pgf@max=\dimen192
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count289
\pgf@shadingcount=\count290
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.cod
e.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.
code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box56
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretranspare
ncy.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.
code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.
tex
File: pgfcorerdf.code.tex 2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.cod
e.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box57
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.
tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-0-65.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen193
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen194
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/verbatim.sty
Package: verbatim 2020-07-07 v1.5u LaTeX2e package for verbatim enhancements
\every@verbatim=\toks37
\verbatim@line=\toks38
\verbatim@in@stream=\read3
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/environ/environ.sty
Package: environ 2014/05/04 v0.3 A new way to define environments

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/trimspaces/trimspaces.sty
Package: trimspaces 2009/09/17 v1.1 Trim spaces around a token list
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count291
)
\tcb@titlebox=\box58
\tcb@upperbox=\box59
\tcb@lowerbox=\box60
\tcb@phantombox=\box61
\c@tcbbreakpart=\count292
\c@tcblayer=\count293
\c@tcolorbox@number=\count294
\tcb@temp=\box62
\tcb@temp=\box63
\tcb@temp=\box64
\tcb@temp=\box65
\tcb@out=\write4
\tcb@record@out=\write5
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbtheorems.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbtheorems.code.tex' version '4.42'
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbskins.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbskins.code.tex' version '4.42'
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
Package: pgffor 2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen195
\pgffor@skip=\dimen196
\pgffor@stack=\toks39
\pgffor@toks=\toks40
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.cod
e.tex
Package: tikz 2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothan
dlers.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count295
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen197
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen198
\tikz@lasty=\dimen256
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen257
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen258
\tikz@lastmovetox=\dimen259
\tikz@lastmovetoy=\dimen260
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen261
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen262
\tikz@figbox=\box66
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box67
\tikz@tempbox=\box68
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box69
\tikztreelevel=\count296
\tikznumberofchildren=\count297
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count298
\tikz@fig@count=\count299

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.cod
e.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count300
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count301
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count302
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count303

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2020/12/27 v3.1.8b (3.1.8b)
)))
\tcb@waterbox=\box70

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbskinsjigsaw.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbskinsjigsaw.code.tex' version '4.42'
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbbreakable.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbbreakable.code.tex' version '4.42'
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdfcol.sty
Package: pdfcol 2019/12/29 v1.6 Handle new color stacks for pdfTeX (HO)
)
Package pdfcol Info: New color stack `tcb@breakable' = 1 on input line 23.
\tcb@testbox=\box71
\tcb@totalupperbox=\box72
\tcb@totallowerbox=\box73
)
No file temp.aux.
\openout1 = `temp.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PU/pdf/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msa on input line 14.

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msb on input line 14.


(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `colorlinks' set `true' on input line 14.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring ON on input line 14.

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2021-04-02 v2.47 Cross-referencing by name of section

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.s
ty
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count304
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 14.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 14.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 14.
\@outlinefile=\write6
\openout6 = `temp.out'.

 (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count305
\scratchdimen=\dimen263
\scratchbox=\box74
\nofMPsegments=\count306
\nofMParguments=\count307
\everyMPshowfont=\toks41
\MPscratchCnt=\count308
\MPscratchDim=\dimen264
\MPnumerator=\count309
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count310
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks42
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
Chapter 1

Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []

 [1


{/Users/tom/Library/texlive/2021/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]

[2] (./temp.aux)

LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.


Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `temp.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.
```

Comment: Please post minimal but complete code, which produces this problem. Thanks

Comment: hyperlinks insert things that can affect spacing. But without a minimal example it is  impossible to debug what is happening here. Also you should test this on a current texlive 2021 to check if the issue has already been already resolved.

Comment: @MS-SPO Well I can't. I have a pretty complex LaTeX file and if I start with a minimal example, things work fine. As I wrote, I already tried to isolate the problem by loading/unloading packages, but without success.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks Ulrike. The problem occurs on TeXLive 2018 and 2021 on macOS, but (for instance) does not on TeXLive 2017 on Ubuntu

Comment: Well you will have to provide a complete example.

Comment: looks ok here. Compile on the newest tex system you have and then show the complete log-file.

Comment: The issue appears only if `\href` has no previous text in the paragraph. On the other hand, `\leavevmode` doesn't cure the issue.

Comment: Adding `\textcompwordmark` in front of `\href` cures the problem. At least there's a workaround.

Comment: By the way, if I compile with XeLaTeX, the issue disappears.

Comment: @egreg Hm, it the example provided above adding `\textcompwordmark` does indeed do the trick, but unfortunately not everywhere throughout my lecture notes. What does seem to work is removing `ocgcolorlinks=true`, but then things look different.